# How to access float style in Literal: 0.7f (float style) in PMD via xpath

Tags: xpath, pmd

[image]

This is a PMD screen shot for part of my code. I am trying to write a Xpath Query in order to determine the Literal in the above screenshot is float style. Is there any way that I can access that "float style"; Currently, I have something like this //EqualityExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimanyPrefix/Literal , now, I do not know how  to access the float style. 
Could anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I just changed the PMD to Checkstyle. I guess probably there is no way for accessing that. But I still keep the question open.  Thanks for any updating

Comment: Okay, I think I was wrong. We can do it via PMD. Check the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath expression should do the trick:

```
//EqualityExpression/PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Literal[@FloatLiteral='true']
```

You can access additional attributes of the Literal. The Designer will show them in the lower left area:

[image: designer screenshot]

There are other attributes such as "DoubleLiteral", "IntLiteral", "LongLiteral", and so on.